# Class Autoloading include file

Tags: 7

Class autoloading isn't working in custom module to extend webforms. Trying to call a function like this:

```
$utility = new webform_kk_utility();
$utility->getComponents('aaa')
```

getting this error:

```
[Mon Sep 21 20:29:28.287580 2015] [:error] [pid 15908] [client ******:39831] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'webform_kk_utility' not found in /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/webform_kk/webform_kk.module on line 12
```

Here's my code:

webform_kk.info:

```
name = Webform kk
description = custom webform code
core = 7.x
package = Webform
dependencies[] = webform
files[] = includes/utility.inc
```

webform_kk.module:

```
<?php

function webform_kk_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_1') {
        $first = array_shift($form['#submit']);
        array_unshift($form['#submit'], $first, 'webform_kk_submit_1');
    }
}

function webform_kk_submit_1(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $utility = new webform_kk_utility();
    echo $utility->getComponents('aaa');
    die();
}
```

includes/utility.inc:

```
<?php

Class webform_kk_utility {
    function getComponents($components) {
        return $components;
    }
}
```

I tested the code without calling the external function, the code is running and the form submit dies where expected. I tried disabling, uninstalling the module and clearing the cache.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Class" -> "class".
It needs to be lowercase, or else Drupal does not discover it while scanning the file.

Comment: What, really?!! Jeez, that's a hell of a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I never would have guessed that! I tried a dozen combinations of changing the actual class name and include file name, thinking the case might need to be different, or the module name should / shouldn't be included in the class.